# Записать во внешний XML файл

Tags: java, android, xml

Подскажите плиз, как сделать так, чтобы записать в XML файл. Попробовал так ,но файл создаётся пустой(

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ "xmlFile.xml"); 
file.createNewFile(); 
FileOutputStream fileos = new FileOutputStream(file); 
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("xmlFile.xml",MODE_APPEND); 
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer(); 
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); 
xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer); 
xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true); 
xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "userData"); 
xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "Date"); 
xmlSerializer.text(m1.dt); 
xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Date"); 
xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"Message"); 
xmlSerializer.text(m1.msg); 
xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Message"); 
xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "userData"); 
xmlSerializer.endDocument(); 
xmlSerializer.flush(); 
String dataWrite = writer.toString(); 
fos.write(dataWrite.getBytes()); 
fos.close();
```

Comment: Для чего создаются и `fileos`, и `fos`?

Comment: я хз зачем fileos но fos чтобы открыть файл. Мне препод сказал в XML записать и прочитать а как это сделать увы он не говорил ,вот и ищу по всяким сайтам и форумам.

Comment: Про сериалиацию не слышал?

Comment: я этим вроде как тут и занимаюсь. Нашёл проблему: openFileOutput не  открывает данный файл.

Comment: Намекну ещё раз: дважды открывается один и тот же файл...

Answer (score 0):

Если записать и прочитать эти данные, то можно использовать пример как  сохранение в TXT, используя SharedPreferences
[Почитай про SharedPreferences и как его использовать](http://www.fandroid.info/en/urok-33-sharedpreferences-sohranenie-dannyh-v-prilozheniyah-uroki-android-studio/)

Comment: я нашёл проблему , openFileOutput не может открыть файл( Но почему хз

Comment: А файл сам физически создается?

Comment: файл создаётся в корневой папке андройда.

Comment: в SharedPreference исползую загрузку такую на чтение изфайла

Comment: а xml файл сохраняется на носителе?

Comment: а для сохранения списка пар это подойдёт? Например мне нужно сохранить даты и события связанные с ними.

Comment: укажи какие поля тебе необходимо сохранять и все!, Можно сохранить все что есть в активити!

Answer (score 0):

```
 loadText() {
    if ( loginInputEmail.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
        String savedTexts = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXTS, "");
        loginInputEmail.setText(savedText);
        loginInputPassword.setText(savedTexts);

        Toast.makeText( LoginActivity.this, "Данные подгружены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Данные не введены. Введите данные и нажмите сохранить, для авто.авторизации", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Сохранение данных  в TXT, используя SharedPreferences